# Deface on spree to override an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, overriding, spree, deface

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm developing a smal e-commerce website based on the spree gem.

However I wanted to update/override the front-end part of the website using the spree deface library.

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/shared/_header',
:name => 'change store logo',
:replace => 'figure#logo',
:text => "<%= image_tag('/images/logo.png') %>"
```

This is my code, but it after reloading the page, the logo gets replaced only by a word 'Logo' and not the image itself. Am I targeting the wrong path? Where should the image files for override be put at?

This is the html of the page:

```
    <div id="spree-header">
  <header id="header" data-hook>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <figure id="logo" class="col-md-4 col-sm-3" data-hook>
          <%= logo %>
        </figure>
        <%= render partial: 'spree/shared/nav_bar' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <%= render partial: 'spree/shared/main_nav_bar' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got how it works.

I needed to base myself on the Ruby Assets pipeline, so the path of the images should be at: railsapplication/apps/assets/images/*.png to be used as an override by deface.

Also the code should be:

```
    Deface:: Override.new(:virutal_path => 'spree/shared/_header', #change this at need
      :name => 'change store logo', #optional
      :replace => 'figure#logo' #id that will be replaced located at /_header
      :text => "<%= link_to image_tag('logos/logo_small.png') %>, #Ruby tag included
    )
```

And should work without a problem.